# What is the best way to cluster binary matrix

Tags: clustering, binary-data

I have a binary matrix in which each student have the session they are enrolled in. I want to cluster students with same sessions. I am a beginner in clustering; which is the best method to do that (k-means, ...)?

Here's an example:

```
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
|  session1  | session2|session3|session4|
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
|     1      |    0    |   1    |    0   |
|     0      |    1    |   0    |    1   |
|     1      |    0    |   1    |    0   | 
|     0      |    1    |   0    |    1   |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+

Result:
clusterA = [user1,user3]
clusterB = [user2,user4]
```

Comment: What do you consider "the best way"? Is this a [`[self-study]`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) question?

Comment: clustering methods are so many and varies according to the data i have.for exemple k-means is not appropriate, because the data is binary and the standard "mean" operation does not make much sense for binary. i'm open to any suggestion